# Light Weight File System

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems

I am trying to develop my own version of ubuntu to use in a real time system that will display parameters of your vehicle.  Capabilities of the system, no media, logging of vehicle metric will take place, script that update application and interface files from flash drive and main application.  Would a lightweight file system free up resources and increase the speed of my overall system.  Does anyone know of a file sytem that would out perform ext4 with a system with minimal reading and writing.

Answer (score 0):

ext2 is going to be the most stable and lightweight you are going to get but you pay a price, on crash, it has to fsck. The other filesystems like ext4 have a journal which helps against this.

It really depends on what you are trying to do. More details would be good.

Answer (score 0):

Filesystem is quite less time consuming than the
physical storage support.

Comment: Well since this is going into a car I was already planning on using a SSD

Comment: SSD is obviously the best option for such an aggressive environment.
As you planned to embed Ubuntu, I assume you'll be using SDCard or USB stick and then you'll prefer EXT3 (=famous ext2 + journalling) or EXT4 or a mix of them: ext3 *mounted as* ext4. 
That way, you'll benefit the multi-block allocator + delayed allocations. And, last but not least, this is reversible if you mount ext3 *as ext3* ! :) 
If I'm wrong and your using a raw Flash chip, you'll prefer UBIFS (formerly JFFS3) as Ubuntu needs space and JFFS2 will be to slow over 256 MiB.